# if $A^X$ is a field, A being a ring, what can be concluded about $A$: field/ unital ring/ division ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ and consider $A^X$, with $X$ a non-empty a set. The operations are point-wise addition and multiplication.  I have proved that $A^X$ is a ring, that it is commutative iff A is commutative and that it is unital iff A is unital

Now I am stuck in this part where they ask to prove or disprove:
**Is $A^X$  a field iff A is a field ? Does one of the implication holds? What can be concluded about A?**

So far:
I know that if A is field, $A^X$ will not be a field because I can always define a function that has 0 in the codomain in at least one point and therefore because 0 doesn't have a multiplicative inverse the whole function will be not invertible. Then the reverse  and the double implication are false.

what about the forward implication?

If $A^X$ is a field, what can I say about $ A$? is it necessarily a field? or  maybe just a division ring or a unital ring?

Comment: The ring $A^X$ is a field (or division ring) iff $A$ is a field (or division ring) and $|X|=1$.

Comment: @Geoffrey Trang For a field the inverse of the function $\phi=\{ (x_0,a)\}$ with $x_0$ the only element of X is $\phi^{-1}=\{ (x_0,a^{-1})\}$ for all $a$ different from zero. Could you help me with the case of a division ring?, in that case the inverse $a^{-1}$ would not unique because since there is no commutativity, there would be  left and right inverses?

Answer (score 2):

So far it seems you're not quite coming to the right conclusion.

If $A$ is a field and $|X|=1$, then $A^X$ is certainly a field.

Functions in $A^X$ (if that's how you're thinking of it) are simply selecting an element of $A$.  Therefore there's a function for every element of $F$, and addition and multiplication take place exactly as they do in $F$. In fact, it's isomorphic to $F$.

What you need to ask is

> What happens when $|X|> 1$?

Then after that,

> What happens when $|X|=1$, but $A$ is not a field?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, there was a suggestion about it but I was not sure why is it important to break it into cases according to the cardinality of $X$. If instead of being a  field , $A$ were just a division ring, for the case |X|=1, can I in the same manner conclude $A^X$ is a division ring? I am having trouble deciding that , because in a division ring, in general elements would have a right and left inverse right?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Maybe it's worth your while to prove this: $A^X\cong \prod_{x\in X} A$.

Comment: Ok I have concluded that if $A$ is a field or division ring and $ |X| >1$ , $A^X$ is not a field or division ring. and if $|X| =1$, it is. The problem is the inverse implication. If $A^X$ is a field or division ring, is $ A$ a field or division ring?Can you help me with that?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO, $A$ embeds into $A^X$.

Comment: @lhf, that means that whatever happens to $A^X$, will happen to $A$? So in this case of $A^X$ is a field , so is $A$

Comment: If $A^X$ is a field (or division ring), you already proved $|X|=1$. So $A^X=A$ is a field (or division ring)